# Generate Key value from a csv file in bash

Tags: bash, hashmap

I'm trying to generate a hashmap from a csv file

```
header1,header2,header3,header4
value1,val2,val3,val4
```

There are about a thousand rows and I'm trying to generate 
value1 header2 "val2" header 3 "val3" header4 "val4"

Comment: Do you want a unique map for each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the test file

```
header1,header2,header3,header4
value1,val2,val3,val4
a,b,c,d
```

We can do

```
declare -A map
{
    # read the first line
    IFS=, read -ra headers

    # iterate over the rest of the lines
    while IFS=, read -ra values; do 
        # create the mapping
        for i in "${!headers[@]}"; do 
            map["${headers[i]}"]=${values[i]}
        done
        # do something with the map
        declare -p map
    done
} < file.csv
```

outputs

```
declare -A map='([header4]="val4" [header1]="value1" [header3]="val3" [header2]="val2" )'
declare -A map='([header4]="d" [header1]="a" [header3]="c" [header2]="b" )'
```

But that seems needlessly complicated. It may be sufficient to have the common indices between the `headers` and `values` arrays.